# Scribe 1.3.3 and maven

Tags: scribe

It looks like that the latest version available in maven central repository is not the latest one (1.3.3) but the previous one (1.3.2). Is there any chance to have it available in maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just uploaded](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.3/) the `1.3.3` artifacts to central. Sorry for the delays